# SHtml.textarea as a CssSel

Tags: lift

Is there any way to create a `CssSel` that has a `SHtml.textarea`/`SHtml.text`/`SHtml.input`/`SHtml.button` logic?

What I want is, having a NodeSeq

```
<textarea class="dontDeletePlease"></textarea>
```

and a CssSel like

```
"*" #> SHtml.textarea(...)
```

have a result

```
<textarea class="dontDeletePlease" onsubmit="..." name="..."></textarea>
```

But, instead, I'll get the class `"dontDeletePlease"` erased. And all other attributes too.

Is there any way to create a CssSel that would apply it's logic keeping the html attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options. You can use Lift's `funcMap` to add the function directly to your existing `textarea`. This will not modify anything except to add a name attribute directly to your tag. This is similar to what [Lift does internally with `SHtml.textarea`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/SHtml.scala#L2132).

```
"*" #> {
  fmapFunc(SFuncHolder((t) => //do something))(funcName =>
    "* [name]" #> funcName
  )
}
```

The other is to grab the attributes from within the CSS Selector and pass them to your transformation, like this:

```
"*" #> { ns:NodeSeq =>
  ns.map{ n =>
    val ta = SHtml.textarea("", (t) => //do something)
    ta % n.attributes
  }
}
```

That will use `SHtml.textarea` to create an input, and then add all of the attributes from the existing element to the new one.

Comment: Eh, lopex from the IRC channel gave me a hint and I understood it about 10 minutes ago.. I wasn't quick enough to answer the question or close it somehow.. Sorry again and thanks for the answer!